# javascript phonegap barcode scanner is so slow

Tags: javascript, cordova, barcode-scanner, phonegap

I'm using phonegap barcode scanner which installed from [Github Phonegap Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

It's working for me on android and ios platforms but scanning barcode is so slow and take long time .

Any helps to increase the the performance .

Thanks

Comment: Strange. I am using the same plugin and so far it has been extremely efficient I found. I have tested on 3 Android devices so far (A3, A50 and S5)

Answer (score 1):

I currently work with barcode (39) and qrcode and when I used this plugin, I have the same problem as you: if the device does not have a 13mpx camera minimum, it takes too long to be industrialize.

Then, i haved test with many full-js library for decoding qrcode and barcode and i haved lot of better result.

So, no i don't think you can really increase plugin performance but you can't try with this solution.

Here is the lib i used for barcode : https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/

And for qrcode : https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR

I had an improvement in the order of 5 to 10 seconds on a Windows tablet and 5Mpx